# Handlebars JS access nested array

Tags: arrays, foreach, handlebars.js, each

Have an array nested inside another array.

```
const data = [
    id: 1,
    plan_name: foo,
    description: foo bar,
    test: [{
           id: 44,
           activity_name: bar,
           comment: var
           },
           {
           id: 45,
           activity_name: var,
           comment: bar
           }],
    userId: 3
];
```

Printing data in a view template using:

```
{{#each data}}
    <p>{{plan_name}}</p>
    <p>{{test}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

The output is:

```
p1
[object Object],[object Object]
p2
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
p3
[object Object],[object Object]
```

How can I access the objects in the nested array using handlebars so that for every instance in the data array all items in the test array are printed?

Comment: Test is an array containing a number of objects. Edited to make it more clear

Comment: Ok, in that case try the code I suggested below.

Comment: This code example should not even work, it's not a correct array syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{{#each data}}
    <p>{{plan_name}}</p>>
    {{#each test}}
        {{activity_name}}
        {{comment}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: That did the trick, this was actually what i tried originally with another result, must have been some magic along the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `#with` handlebar to access the object

```
{{#each data}}
    <p>{{plan_name}}</p>>
    {{#with test}}
        {{activity_name}}
        {{comment}}
    {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Still getting the same output for some reason, feels like it should work though

Comment: Getting this output now instead `p1

>
p3

>
p3

>`

Comment: Is ‘test’ meant to be an object? If so it should be enclosed within  curly brackets {} instead of []. If it’s an array or objects then each object should be within the curly bracket like test=[{id:1, ..}, {id:2,..}]. If it’s an object, then the suggestion above should work.